# Where is defined orderProp in AngularJS and why is not present in API documentation?

Tags: angularjs, properties, models

I started to study AngularJS from the official tutorial and at a [certain point](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_06#component-controller), it use:

```
this.orderProp = 'age';
```

To give the possibility to order the list based on `age`. Now the question became inevitable:"What are the other properties? and where is the doc for `orderProp`" I tried to search it in API documentation without any success.

I supposed the orderProp was something related to the `orderBy`, but is not mentioned.

Comment: Can you post the exact spot in the documentation that you found that reference?  This doesn't sound like something related to the API; rather, it sounds like an input somewhere on the page with `ng-model="orderProp"` defined on it.  `orderProp` could be any valid JavaScript name.

Comment: Yes of course! Updated with the link.

Comment: That confirms my suspicion.  in the HTML, the `ng-repeat` is filtered with `orderBy:$ctrl.orderProp`.  `$ctrl` and `this` are interchangeable in this context, and `orderProp` could be any valid name.  This also refers to the `<select ng-model="$ctrl.orderProp">` in the same HTML, which gives you another way to change the property value.

Comment: in other words, `orderProp` wouldn't be documented in the API documentation because it's not part of the API, it is a property defined for this example.  in your app, you could use any variable you like.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks for the explanation!